# webpack splitting code by module

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router

since my react app bundle.js is too big, so I want to splitting it by module(via react router)

(react, react-router 4)

app is only endpoint and I import every sub-app router in app

what our module system like: 
app 
--> subApp1 
--> subApp2 
--> subApp3

how I import sub-app now:

```
// app.js
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import SubApp1 from '../SubApp1'
import SubApp2 from '../SubApp2'
import SubApp3 from '../SubApp3'

const App = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route path="sub-app1" component={SubApp1} />
    <Route path="sub-app2" component={SubApp2} />
    <Route path="sub-app3" component={SubApp3} />
  <Switch>
)
```

right now, there was an app.bundle.js containing app and sub-apps and I import it in `index.html`

what I want is:

```
// index.html
<script src="/static/subApp1.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="/static/subApp2.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="/static/subApp3.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="/static/app.bundle.js"></script>

    // app.js
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import SubApp1 from 'SubApp1'
import SubApp2 from 'SubApp2'
import SubApp3 from 'SubApp3'

const App = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route path="sub-app1" component={SubApp1} />
    <Route path="sub-app2" component={SubApp2} />
    <Route path="sub-app3" component={SubApp3} />
  <Switch>
)
```

I can splitting every subapps to sub-bundle by webpack (multiple entries), however I can not import them in `app.js`

anyone know how to configure webpack.config.js to implement it?

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to configure Webpack. it will review the imports and automatically create the bundle and the AJAX loader for importing at run time.

Try the following.

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

function asyncComponent(getComponent) {
  return class AsyncComponent extends React.Component<any,any> {
    static Component = null;
    state = { Component: AsyncComponent.Component };

    componentWillMount() {
      if (!this.state.Component) {
        getComponent().then(Component => {
          AsyncComponent.Component = Component
          this.setState({ Component })
        })
      }
    }
    render() {
      const { Component } = this.state
      if (Component) {
        return <Component {...this.props} />
      }
      return null
    }
  }
}

const FooComponent = asyncComponent(() => (
  System.import('./foo').then(module => module.default)
));

const BarComponent = asyncComponent(() => (
  System.import('./bar').then(module => module.default)
));

const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Link to="/">Home</Link>
      <Link to="/foo">Foo</Link>
      <Link to="/bar">Bar</Link>
      <Route path="/foo" component={FooComponent} />
      <Route path="/bar" component={BarComponent} />
     </div>
  </Router>
 );
 
 
 render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

PS, most of this code I stole from Kent Dodds :)

Comment: `System.import` is deprecated. Official documentation recommends to use `require.ensure` or `import()`

Comment: This is not standardised yet so nothing is official/deprecated. I use Webpack/TypeScript and both support System.import

Comment: Official documentation of `webpack` :) https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/ They advice to use `import()` which is friendly-spec rather than `System.import` which was only an internal tweak. Eventually it will be deprecated to it's better to propose code that will be maintained instead of deprecated

Comment: ahh you're talking about Webpack and not JavaScript. We are not set yet, TC39 still at process 3 (so not a standard). Webpack will still support both until it hits process 4. https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import/blob/master/README.md